# NodeJS change session variable after redirect

Tags: node.js, express, npm, express-session

I have a login system, user posts data to /login route and it saves data if logged correctly.

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  if(req.method == 'POST') {
    const username = req.body.username;
    const password = req.body.password;
    sql.query('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = "'+username+'"', function(err, results) {
      if(err) { 
        req.session.message = {status: 'danger', message: 'Failed to login, check password.'}
        res.redirect('/')
      } else if (results.length != 0) {
        const passw = results[0].password;
        bcrypt.compare(password, passw, function(err, result) {
          if(result) {
            req.session.loggedin = true;
            req.session.data = results[0];
            req.session.message = {status: 'success', message: `Welcome back, ${username}.`}
            req.session.save(function(err) {
                res.redirect(req.headers.referer);
            })
          } else {
            req.session.message = {status: 'danger', message: 'Failed to login, check password.'}
            res.redirect('/')
          }
        });
      } else {
        req.session.message = {status: 'danger', message: 'Failed to login, check username.'}
        res.redirect('/')
      }
    })
  }
});
```

so it saves the data and redirects to index but everytime a user goes on the index page it shows the Welcome message, it obviously does this because the variable is still defined so my goal is to change that variable too null after they login and the welcome message shows up once.

ive tried:

```
delete req.session.message
```

but this just deletes the variable before it gets passed to the next request.

How im displaying the message:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var message = JSON.parse('<%- JSON.stringify(message) %>');
   $(document).ready(function(){
      if(message != null) {
         $('.toast').addClass('bg-' + message.status);
         $('.toast-body').html(message.message)
         $(".toast").toast('show');
      }
   });        
</script>
```

How im rendering the data:

```
if(req.session.loggedin) {
    res.render('index', {
        loggedin: true,
        data: req.session.data,
        message: req.session.message
    });
} else {
    res.render('index', {
        loggedin: false,
        data: null,
        message: req.session.message
  });
}
```

Comment: I think folks would need to see more of the code for the login process.  It seems you should be clearing the `req.session.message` and making sure that is saved to the session AFTER you've displayed the message once.  You don't show where or how you're  displaying the message so not sure how to help.  So, you aren't showing the code where the message should be displayed and aren't show the code where the message should not be displayed.

Comment: @jfriend00 the issue isnt about how im displaying the code (jquery) because im using it for other routes aswell for showing users errors and etc, the issue is everytime the user goes to a page with the rendered data (req.session.message) it displays it, i want to 'reset' the session variable after the request redirects the user.

Comment: Well, you need to clear the message from the session IN the request that displays the message.  You render the message into your template and then you clear the session so that no future http requests will see the message.  So, the code where you should clear the message is NOT shown in your question.  You also have to be very careful in your login detection code that you're not accidentally resetting the message when the user is already logged in.  Can't help you with just the code you are showing now.

Comment: @jfriend00 ive added all the neccesary code, please take a look and let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you render your page containing the message, you need to clear the message from the session:

```
if (req.session.loggedin) {
    res.render('index', {
        loggedin: true,
        data: req.session.data,
        message: req.session.message
    });
} else {
    res.render('index', {
        loggedin: false,
        data: null,
        message: req.session.message
    });
}
req.session.message = null;
req.session.save();
```

And, to avoid any chance of a race condition between a redirect and saving the session, you should not redirect until you've manually saved the session.  The issue is that relying on the auto-save of the session by express-session will attempt to save the session AFTER you send the `res.redirect()`, but sending the `res.redirect()` tells the browser to immediately request another page so you set up a race between the auto-save of the session and the new incoming request from `res.redirect()`.  You don't want that race.  You want to make sure the session has been saved before you issue the redirect.  So, I put the `res.redirect()` inside a `req.session.save()` callback to avoid any possible race condition:

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  if(req.method == 'POST') {
    const username = req.body.username;
    const password = req.body.password;
    sql.query('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = "'+username+'"', function(err, results) {
      if(err) { 
        req.session.message = {status: 'danger', message: 'Failed to login, check password.'}
        res.redirect('/')
      } else if (results.length != 0) {
        const passw = results[0].password;
        bcrypt.compare(password, passw, function(err, result) {
          if(result) {
            req.session.loggedin = true;
            req.session.data = results[0];
            req.session.message = {status: 'success', message: `Welcome back, ${username}.`}
            req.session.save(function(err) {
                res.redirect(req.headers.referer);
            })
          } else {
            req.session.message = {status: 'danger', message: 'Failed to login, check password.'}
            req.session.save(() => {
                res.redirect('/')
            });
          }
        });
      } else {
        req.session.message = {status: 'danger', message: 'Failed to login, check username.'}
        req.session.save(() => {
            res.redirect('/')
        });
      }
    })
  }
});
```